# MySQL query not quite right...probably pretty simple

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, max

I've got a table for a payroll system, with four fields, and some sample data:

```
pkref  employee_id  new_wage  effective_date
=====  ===========  ========  ==============
23     06031-BOB    10        080101
37     06031-BOB    15        090501
90     06031-BOB    13        110228
```

When an employee's wage is changed, a primary key reference auto-increments, and the appropriate information is recorded (`effective_date` is a timestamp, yymmdd).  No problems there.

Now, I'm trying to get a query to find

1. All entries related to an employee, then
2. The maximum `effective_date` stamp in those sub-entries
3. The wage that corresponds to that maximum.

I've made my very first subquery ever (!), got it almost right, but it's buggy.  Could some guru have a look and give me a bump in the right direction?

`SELECT MAX(effective_date),new_wage FROM (SELECT effective_date,new_wage FROM hr_wages WHERE employee_code='06031-BOB') AS t1`

Ideally, I want `110228` and `13` to be returned. But, as the aforementioned guru will no doubt see immediately, something is wrong.  The `new_wage` value does not always match the max `effective_date`.

So. Vat to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hang on, what's stopping you from doing the following?

```
select effective_date, new_wage from hr_wages
where employee_code = '06031-BOB'
order by effective_date desc
limit 1
```

Comment: For one employee i think maybe is the best choise. +1

Answer (score 1):

For only one employee you can use IN with subquery

```
   SELECT new_wage, other data... 
    FROM hr_wages
    WHERE effective_date IN (SELECT max(effective_date) FROM hr_wages WHERE employee_code='06031-BOB')
AND employee_code='06031-BOB' -- Corrected: Credits to Stev
```

e

For all employees

```
SELECT new_wage, CO 
FROM hr_wages w LEFT JOIN
(SELECT max(effective_date) effective_date, employee_code 
FROM hr_wages 
GROUP BY employee_code
)d ON w.employee_code = d.employee.code AND w.effective_date = d.effective_date
```

Comment: +1 since you got me on the right direction, but your first query returns many `new_wage` values, not the one that corresponds to the single employee.  I modified it a bit and came out with the code in my solution.  You're welcome to copy/paste/beautify that, and when the query spits out that one value, I can accept with good conscience.  :)  Don't really want to accept my own answer...you're the guru I was seeking.

Comment: What matter's is you found solution to your problem! The rest of us learn from each other!

Comment: now she's workin' well.  But sorry mate gotta go with @shylent's more elegant solution.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

There was a post from @niktrs that provided the right answer, but it's been deleted!

So, here's the query I was looking for, with @niktrs help.  If his post comes back, I'll accept it.

```
SELECT new_wage FROM hr_wages WHERE effective_date IN 
(SELECT effective_date,new_wage FROM hr_wages  WHERE employee_code='06031-BOB') 
AND employee_code='06031-BOB'
```

This ugliness can be beautified, I'm sure.

Comment: Reposted! For one minute i thought I missed something

Comment: I also missed something in the where and corrected thanks to you!